# Why can't a class attribute from a container tag affect a nested table element inside it the container tag

Tags: html, css

I have a class attribute inside a `<div>` tag that changes the `color:` property. I'm wondering why in this case why that class attribute doesn't change the nested table element's properties, as the nested h1 element in the container tag has its color changed.

I have tried putting the class attribute in the table element and that solved the problem, but I'm wondering why the class attribute in the div tag doesn't affect the table element's properties for the code below. Thank you if someone answers.

```css
.test {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">

  <h1>dog facts</h1>
  
  <table border="1" style="width: 90%;">
    <tr style="height: 50px;">
      <th style="font-size: 20px;" colspan="3">
        <p>Table of Contents</p>
        <p style="font-size: 15px;">(click the links below to jump to desired section)</p>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your posted code works as expected. Do you have more CSS targeting the other elements?

Comment: It seems like that is likely the problem. When I removed the other CSS stuff the code works, thank you.